# How to add an interactive visualization to R markdown

Tags: r, d3.js, r-markdown

My question is I want to integrate a d3.js visualization to my markdown rather than a link pointing to the visualization on external website. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: What kind of visualization? ggvis, or d3 you're writing yourself?

Comment: What about an iframe?

Comment: hi @DavidRobinson it is the visualization I wrote by myself

Comment: @TylerRinker i was thinking about iframe as well but how could i integrate iframe in rmarkdown?

Comment: @MYjx: rmarkdown allows the inclusion of HTML. Just write some in.

Comment: @DavidRobinson thanks! but how could i integrate some js libraries into the html?

Comment: does this help http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html (see custom css and document dependencies)?

Comment: I realize this is vague, so putting a real answer together now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To accomplish adding nonlocal javascript such as `d3.v3.min.js` to our Rmd, there are a couple ways to do it.  If you are looking to include local copy of `d3`, it is much easier.

This is my favorite way.  If for some reason, you would like to see the others, I will be happy to show them.  **Note: I am still experimenting.**

````
---
title: "rmarkdown example with external js"
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: false
    keep_md: true
    includes:
      in_header: "header_include_d3.html"
---

Let's create a very basic d3 graph using data from R.  since the graph is d3, we will need the d3.js file for the graph to render.

```{r results='asis'}

cat('
<script>
  d3.select("body").append("p").text("d3 made me")
</script>
')

```

<script>

// from https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js
//The data for our line
 var lineData = [ { "x": 1,   "y": 5},  { "x": 20,  "y": 20},
                  { "x": 40,  "y": 10}, { "x": 60,  "y": 40},
                  { "x": 80,  "y": 5},  { "x": 100, "y": 60}];

 //This is the accessor function we talked about above
 var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                          .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
                          .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
                         .interpolate("linear");

//The SVG Container
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 200)
                                    .attr("height", 200);

//The line SVG Path we draw
var lineGraph = svgContainer.append("path")
                            .attr("d", lineFunction(lineData))
                            .attr("stroke", "blue")
                            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                            .attr("fill", "none");

</script>
````

then in the same directory as this .Rmd file, save this

```
<script src = "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

into a file I called `header_include_d3.html` or whatever name you would like.  If you change the name, just be sure to change the reference in the `includes` in the `yaml` of your Rmd.

As I said before, this is much easier if you have d3.js locally that you would like to use.

Also, `<script src='...'></script>` inside the body will work if you are not particular about have your js in the header.  In that case, just include it anywhere in the Rmd.

Answer (score 5):

You have now the [R2D3](https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3/) package that allows that! 
Rmardown is one way of including D3 visualisation in R
https://rstudio.github.io/r2d3/articles/publishing.html#r-markdown