# html - plotting two heatmaps with leaflet

Tags: html, leaflet

I'm trying to plot two heatmaps in one document using [Leaflet.Heat](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat). However, in the first map the **heat** stays in position relative to the frame of the map (i.e. it doesn't move when you zoom in/out of the map). The second map behaves as expected.

Both maps should be identical, so what have I missed?

**Note:** `html` isn't a language I'm particularly familiar with so I may have missed something obvious, this code will end up in an [`r markdown` document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33359406/4002530)

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
<!-- heatmap-->
<div id="map1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"></script>
<style>
  #map1 { width: 800px; height: 600px; }
  body { font: 16px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; }
  .ghbtns { position: relative; top: 4px; margin-left: 5px; }
  a { color: #0077ff; }
</style> 

<script>
  var map1 = L.map('map1').setView([47.5982623,-122.3415519], 12);
  var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    }).addTo(map1);
  var heat = L.heatLayer([[47.5982623,-122.3415519, 20], [47.6182623,-122.3417519,50]]).addTo(map1);
</script>
</div>

Plotting another map

<div id="map2">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"></script> 
<style>
  #map2 { width: 800px; height: 600px; }
  body { font: 16px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; }
  .ghbtns { position: relative; top: 4px; margin-left: 5px; }
  a { color: #0077ff; }
</style> 

<script>
  var map2 = L.map('map2').setView([47.5982623,-122.3415519], 12);
  var tiles = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    }).addTo(map2);
  var heat = L.heatLayer([[47.5982623,-122.3415519, 20], [47.6182623,-122.3417519,50]]).addTo(map2); 
</script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Update - solution**

After a lot of trial and error, removing the second

```
<script scr="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js
```

solved it. I don't know why this is the cause of the error so if anyone can provide an explanation in an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out, you need only one instance of leaflet script and you can re-use it to create multiple maps. Same goes for your plugins: loading them only once is enough. Generally this is true for all JavaScript libraries: refrain from loading the same file more than once. So you should get rid of the 2nd loading of "leaflet-heat.js" as well if you have not done so yet.

What happens is purely due to the specified behaviour of JavaScript. The 2nd leaflet load overrides the global `L` variable. The previous content of `L` still exists in memory and is still linked to your first `map`, `tiles` and `heat`. That is why the first map is still working (you can zoom and pan using keyboard navigation).

However, the first heat map is not (which prevents panning by dragging with the mouse). That is because the Leaflet.heat plugin is not wrapped following a module definition technique (e.g. [UMD](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2014/what-is-amd-commonjs-and-umd/)), so it plugs on the initial `L` (i.e. when it is loaded), while using the current `L` during interaction (hence the new value after leaflet is re-loaded). This discrepancy breaks its algorithm and introduces unexpected behaviour, like you have seen your heat map getting re-drawn but not updated (value and position). The 2nd heat map is fine because it plugs and uses the same value of `L` (the re-loaded one).

But if that plugin did not make any use of `L` after loading, or correctly referred to what it was initially, it would not have broken. As you see, loading the same script file several times may or may not introduce bugs, depending on how the algorithm is built. *That is exactly why the module definition technique  was invented.*

There is also an [`L.noConflict` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#noconflict) available to address such cases, but it would not help in your very case because of Leaflet.heat plugin not being wrapped as a module as said above, so even if you use this trick, either the first or the second heat map gets broken.

If that plugin were corrected, everything would have worked magically. Could be the opportunity to open an issue on the plugin GitHub repo and point out this non-compliance (by Leaflet author himself… :-)) with [Leaflet recommendation](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/PLUGIN-GUIDE.md#module-loaders).

Demo of loading Leaflet and Leaflet.heat twice, but with the 2nd plugin through module definition: http://jsfiddle.net/psraudy5/ (so it still needs to call `L.noConflict` to restore the 1st heat map behaviour).

By the way, do not forget to correct the closing tag of your second script call: `</s cript>` should be `</script>`. Browsers should be smart enough to tolerate that mistake though. Web technologies are built to tolerate many mistakes, but the drawback is that they can silently introduce bugs, like in the case of your initial post.

Comment: Going to take me a while to digest all that :) - Thanks for the detailed explanation, and pointer to my `</s cript>` error.